# Android Image and Toolbar(EditText) inside CollapsingToolbarLayout Scrolling

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to implement the function shown below.

[image]

Before scrolling, there is an EditText at the bottom, a logo ImageView in the center, and a right Menu at the top.

During scrolling, the ImageView and the EditText disappear and the Menu remains.

After scrolling, the EditText is reduced to the appropriate size and the Menu is on the right.

However, in my current code, scrollFlag to scroll in CollapsingToolbarLayout does not clicked, nor does it shrink to the proper size.

Here is my Code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/app_logo_150x30"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:hint="@string/menu_search"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextSecondary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

How do I make it work as an attached image?

Answer (score 0):

Old post. But still if people looking for answers, just add app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" in imageview.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/app_logo_150x30"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Import the required settings. Hope it helps.